# yAxis formatter sometimes receives 0 for this.value

Tags: highcharts

I could be wrong, but I think this might well be a bug of some kind:

http://jsfiddle.net/bRgUb/

```
               yAxis: {
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return convertSecondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(this.value);
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Time (h, min, s)'
                }
```

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting, but if I return this.value directly, the yAxis labels are -2500, 0, 2500, 5000 etc. That looks right to me.

Comment: PS: If I were you I would set yAxis.type to "datetime", so that the ticks fall into more natural positions: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/bRgUb/1/. It also makes your conversion function obsolete.

Comment: Could you be more specific what is wrong ?

Comment: Look at the labels on the y axis, one of them is "00:00:00". Yet, there is no zero y value if my data series. The label is "00:00:00" because the formatter gets called with this.value = 0. How can this be right?

Comment: @TorsteinHønsi See my reply below. There is no zero y data value in my series, so why would the formatter receive a call with this.value equal to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Y axis is extended past the data range because of the default values for yAxis.minPadding and yAxis.startOnTick (see api.highcharts.com#yAxis).

Here's your fiddle with those settings set to 0 and false: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/bRgUb/2/

```
            yAxis: {
                startOnTick: false,
                minPadding: 0
            },
```

I still recommend that you use type: "datetime" for the yAxis.

Comment: Thank you, Torstein, I agree that your changes fixes the problem. I just don't know if it hides the problem or fixes it, though. In any case, that works for me. Thanks for helping!

Comment: As for using datetime on the yAxis, I don't know about that. These values are not datetime values, they are durations.

Comment: Datetime points or durations - it's the same thing. Hours, minutes, seconds.

Comment: Indeed, thanks again! So, the mapped post-processing is because the time values are supposed to be stated in milliseconds?